# Encoding/Decoding multi-type fields in JSON golang

Tags: json, go, encoding, marshalling

I am trying to create a struct where a field can hold data of a few particular types, say `int`, `string` and a `CustomType`. I want to decode/encode this struct to/from JSON. How can we achieve this in go/golang?

For example, I have a struct for the following definition:

```
type MyData struct {
  Name  string                                    `json:"name"`
  Value int32                                     `json:"value"`
  Param <can be either int, string or CustomType> `json:"param"`
}
```

Where `CustomType` is

```
type CustomType struct {
  Custom bool `json:"custom"`
}
```

Let's say I need to unmarshal the following JSONs to the above struct `MyData`:

```
{
  "name": "Hello",
  "value": 32
  "param": "World"
}
```

And this one:

```
{
  "name": "Hello",
  "value": 32
  "param": 100
}
```

And this one also:

```
{
  "name": "Hello",
  "value": 32
  "param": {
     "custom": true
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Can I define my own `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` on `MyData` and achieve this?

Or is there a way of defining a custom type, say `IntOrStringOrCustom` and define `MyData` as

```
type MyData struct {
  Name  string              `json:"name"`
  Value int32               `json:"value"`
  Param IntOrStringOrCustom `json:"param"`
}
```

and then define `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` on `IntOrStringOrCustom`?

I have also seen `json.RawMessage`. Can we use it somehow here?

Issue with using `interface{}` is that I will have to write the encoding/decoding logic everywhere, where I am trying to use this data. Or is there an elegant way of doing this with `interface{}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATED. `interface` gets encoded and decoded to JSON well automatically. If you wish to control types, you may add special `UnmarshalJSON` and perform checks in it:

```
type TheParam interface{}

type MyData struct {
    Name  string   `json:"name"`
    Value int32    `json:"value"`
    Param TheParam `json:"param"`
}

type myData MyData

func (m *MyData) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var mm myData
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &mm); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch mm.Param.(type) {
    case float64, string, map[string]interface{}:
        *m = MyData(mm)
        return nil
    default:
        return InvalidFieldTypeError{value: mm.Param}
    }
    return nil
}
```

Type `InvalidFieldTypeError` may be convenient to return such class of errors and can be defined as:

```
type InvalidFieldTypeError struct {
    value interface{}
}

func (e InvalidFieldTypeError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Field type '%T' is not valid for MyData", e.value)
}
```

The whole example: https://play.golang.org/p/MuW6gwSAKi

Also I'd like to recommend this article https://attilaolah.eu/2013/11/29/json-decoding-in-go/

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I want to be able to restrict unmarshalling to only the specified types. Using and interface will result in successful unmarshallling for any kind of values for the key. Is there anyway that can be done?

Comment: Thanks again Eugene. We had tried this method and it works. But the problem is that we have lots of structs where this validation has to happen. So, writing `MarshaJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` for every struct is not a feasible solution. Sadly, I can't write these methods for an `interface{}`. Otherwise I would have written it for `TheParam`.

But, we found another method in which we can do struct validations by adding `validate` tags using packages like https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator. Trying them out now. Will update if that's the way to go forward

Comment: I am checking out the link you shared.

Comment: Only way to do this is to define `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` for every type. Macro support would have made this easier.